# How to correctly curl and stop a Docker container in the CI/CD pipeline of the Bitbucket?

Tags: docker, bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I created a Docker build step in my Bitbucket pipeline. The idea is to pull the image -> build the container -> curl the container. After this sequence, this step is completed.

Here is the part of the code for this Bitbucket pipeline step:

```
docker-test: &docker-test-step
  name: docker-test
...
...
... 
...
script:
        - docker run -p 8080:8080 -e DVC_BEARER_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token) -e MODEL_DIR="model_checkpoints/$MODEL_TYPE/$CUSTOMER/" $IMAGE
        - echo "RUN SUCCESSFULLY"
        - echo "curl http://localhost:8080/"
```

In my Bitbucket pipelines, I could observe how the runner runs `docker run` command. After the docker run command, I observe this output in Bitbucket pipelines:

```
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

This means that the container exists and works. But the step is not finished in pipelines (it is not green (i.e., completed)) and has the status "running".

My questions are how to adapt the bitbucket.yaml file to finish this docker-test step and move further to  `- echo "RUN SUCCESSFULLY"`, `- echo "curl http://localhost:8080/"` steps?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the container with the `--detach` option. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options

```
 script:
   - docker run --detach # ...
   # ...
```

Heads up: this will immediately proceed without waiting the container to be ready so your immediate curl probe will fail anyway.